# What is the earliest source containing the 'Stabat Mater' melody from the 1961 Liber Usualis?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, resource-request, music

I would like to find the earliest source containing the [*Stabat Mater*](https://gregobase.selapa.net/chant.php?id=681) melody on [page 1634V from *The Liber Usualis*](https://archive.org/details/TheLiberUsualis1961/page/n1873/mode/1up), Solesmes, 1961 edition:

[image]

If the earliest source is not known, I would like a source before 1961.

I checked the 1896 *Liber Usualis* (pg 1229) and the 1924 *Liber Usualis* (pg 1644), but both have a different melody.

Comment: That melody isn't just used for that _Stabat sancta Maria_.

Comment: Someone changed my post.  This is not the hymn I asked about.  It's Stabat Mater dolorosa on page 1634V (not 1634).  I see why that's confusing.  It's on the next page at the bottom.

Comment:  I fixed it, and your Archive.org link.

Comment: See [the top most similar chants to this _Stabat Mater_ you cite](https://isidore.co/isogrego/?id=681&n=64).

Comment: interesting.  i went through them.  the only one i could find that matched and was earlier than 1961 was the version in the Graduale Romanum, Vatican, 1908, p. 404.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the 1661 [*Mainz Gesangbuch* p. 298](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/en/view/bsb10590277?page=326,327):

[image: 1661 Mainz Gesangbuch p. 298]

source: [CPDL](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Stabat_Mater)

Comment: The link you posted takes me to a different melody.

Comment: @R.B.Jawad I've added an image from the original 1661 *Mainz Gesangbuch*.

Comment: that’s also not the same melody.  neither the soprano nor the bass match.

Answer (score -1):

I can't say this is the earliest, but the version in [Graduale Romanum, Vatican, 1908, p. 403](https://gregobase.selapa.net/chant.php?id=3887) appears to be largely identical. That would make it earlier, at least.

[image]